How to register a model from a snowflake stage?
I have model stored in snowflake stage which forcast the revenue for the given dataset.
now i want to register the model in snowflake as an endpoint function which can accept the input data and return the forcast value?
I looked into the
snowflake.snowpark.functions.sproc

but it doesn't give a clarity to register the model as function/stored procedure endpoint?
so what is the best way to register a model from existing stage in snowflake?
